# Auto share files synced to Sharepoint Online document library using OneDrive Pro

Tags: onedrive, sharepoint, office365

I'm setting up a new document library in SharePoint Online as part of a team site. This library is synced to all team member computers using OneDrive Pro.

When a document is added to the library by a user in their OneDrive local drive, it isn't visible until they go onto SharePoint Online and share it.

Is it possible to make it the default that any documents synced up to a document library are shared with all library members?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I identified that documents that are synced from OneDrive are considered drafts by the document library. Even if approval is turned off, it won't be visible unless the default setting for draft documents is changed.

Settings > Versioning Settings > Who should see draft items in this document library? > Any user who can read items

This setting makes synced documents visible to all users who have permission to view them.